# How to apply transfer learning on a time-to-failure problem?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, statistics, transfer-learning

I am working on predicting mechanical failures and I have trained a model to predict when a component will fail on what type of machine.

I would like to now use this prediction model to predict when the next type of machine will fail. both type of machines were tested under some similar conditions so they have some overlapping features. However I am not entirely familiar with the algorithnms used for transfer learning and could do with a bit of guidance on how to choose the appropriate approaches and what to consider. I have read some papers and know the main categories of instance based, feature based and model parameter based but knowing which of this 3 would work best for my task is something I am not able to determine. Any advice?